# Oracle 11g: enforce a relationship between two columns in a select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in my db which stores rows by an id and version in two separate columns e.g.,

```
ID VERSION DATA

1    1      ...

1    2      ...

2    1      ...

2    2      ...
```

What i want to do is a "select * where id and version in" query but I'm not sure of a way to keep the id and version linked, for example if my input was id_verList[(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)].

The results i want to get back with this input and the example table would be the first 3 rows but

`select * from table where id in (1,1,2) and version in (1,2,1)`

would return all 4 rows as the two lists are not linked.

Is there a way to enforce a relationship between the id and version without altering the table to have a combined id_ver column.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
 FROM table_name
 WHERE (id,version) IN ((1,1), (1,2), (2,1))
```

More info: [Expression Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions015.htm#SQLRF52079)

Comment: Perfect now just to figure out how to get my input in that form, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE (ID = 1 AND VERSION = 1) OR
        (ID = 1 AND VERSION = 2) OR
        (ID = 2 AND VERSION = 1);
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I should of mentioned this will be part of a stored proc and involve a lot larger set of id/versions and your solution while it will work for this case is not practical for the real situation.